# Dart singleton returning null values

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my singleton, I have a function called init() that sets all the class values, but when I try to use the values are null.

```
class Paths {
  static final Paths _paths = Paths._internal();
  String? authority;
  String? genders;
  Map<String, String>? email;
  Map<String, String>? account;
  Map<String, String>? story;
  Map<String, String>? user;

  factory Paths() => _paths;

  Paths._internal();

  static void init() {
    rootBundle.loadStructuredData<void>('assets/paths/paths.json',
      (jsonStr) async {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonStr);
        _paths.authority = data[Strings.authority] as String;
        _paths.genders = data[Strings.genders] as String;
        _paths.email = Map<String,String>.from(data[Strings.email]);
        _paths.account = Map<String,String>.from(data[Strings.account]);
        _paths.story = Map<String,String>.from(data[Strings.story]);
        _paths.user = Map<String,String>.from(data[Strings.user]);
  });

  }
}
```

```
Paths.init();
Paths paths = Paths();
print(paths.authority); /// prints null
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `AssetBundle.loadStructuredData` is an asynchronous function.  You neglect to wait for it to complete.  More specifically, your `init` function does not `await` `loadStructuredData`'s `Future` before returning, your `init` function also will need to return a `Future`, callers of `Paths.init()` will need to `await` too, etc.

Comment: You are right, I changed the loadStructuredData for loadString, and waited for the string data, works fine now, thanks!

Comment: Actually using loadString.then((){}) works better, that way I don't need to use async

Comment: Using `Future.then` that way still won't allow callers to be notified when the operation completes.  If that doesn't matter (i.e. your function is "fire-and-forget"), then still can use `async`/`await` but make your function return `void` instead of a `Future`.